# RestKit: "article" & "articles" keyPaths - do I need 2 different descriptors?

Tags: restkit

I can get single "article" or an array of "articles". Mapping is the same. But `keyPath` will be "article" or "articles". Do I need 2 different descriptors? Or can I combine it into one somehow? (as an example - Ruby on Rails can recognize single-multiple automatically).

Currently I'm doing it separately, **Single**:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *articleDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:articleMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"article" statusCodes:statusCodes];
[_manager addResponseDescriptor:articleDescriptor];
```

**Multiple:**

```
RKResponseDescriptor *articlesArrayDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:articleMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"articles" statusCodes:statusCodes];
[_manager addResponseDescriptor:articlesArrayDescriptor];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multiple descriptors. Usually you would want to set the `pathPattern` parameter to something specific on your response descriptors anyway to aid performance and prevent the creating of unwanted objects as always setting the `pathPattern` to nil will mean that RestKit can't filter out invalid descriptors for the received data and will need to process them. So, any overlap of key paths in your responses will start to generate (usually empty) object creations that you don't want.